# expand ssh hostname in shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a couple of hosts configured in ~/.ssh/config, for example:

```
Host SomeHost
  Hostname 10.0.0.3
  User SomeUser
```

I'm trying to get the hostname part (10.0.0.3) as a variable from inside a shell script (the %h variable).
Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Short of parsing the file yourself, no. The configuration doesn't exist outside of the file until `ssh` reads it when executed, and `ssh` doesn't provide an API for querying configurations.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- what problem are you're *really* trying to solve?

Comment: @glennjackman I'm trying to use nmap to see if the remote host has port 22 open. It is much faster than using ssh to use a test connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
host2ip() {
    awk -v host="$1" '
        $1 == "Host" && $2 == host {have_host = 1}
        have_host && $1 == "Hostname" {print $2; exit}
    ' ~/.ssh/config
}

ip=$(host2ip SomeHost)
echo $ip
```

```
10.0.0.3
```